# Multiple players considered last on Charity board in Medieval Academy

Tags: medieval-academy

The rules state that when multiple players are at square 0, all of them are considered last on that track. But there's only one -10 Chivalry Points token for the Charity track. What happens if two players are considered last on this track?

Comment: Would you consider creating a tag wiki for the new [medieval-academy] tag so that it doesn't get purged by the system? At you're rep, you'll need to get it approved, but you'll get rep when the approval goes through.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the rules (quoted below) cleary state that in case of a tie on the "0" spot of the track, all tied players are supposed to get the whole penalty. I would use substitute (unused coat of arms for a value of -10 for instance) to track that...

> If your disc has never moved on a track, you are automatically
>   considered last on that track. As such, you can not get
>   anything positive from that game board (no positive Chivalry
>   Points, no bonus from the Gallantry game board), or if it is
>   a game board that gives negative points, you and every other
>   player on square 0 of that track will be considered last and
>   will get the corresponding coat of arms. If 2 or more player
>   get last place this way, no negative points will be given to the
>   players ranked second to last.

Comment: Considering it scores only in the 6th and final round of the game it would be easy to say that using a different token would be more confusing then just remembering who all gets -10 for that item.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at page 6 of the [rules](http://www.iellogames.com/downloads/MedievalAcademy_EN_Rules.pdf)

> f your disc has never moved on a track, you are automatically
>   considered last on that track. As such, you can not get
>   anything positive from that game board (no positive Chivalry
>   Points, no bonus from the Gallantry game board), or if it is
>   a game board that gives negative points, you and every other
>   player on square 0 of that track will be considered last and
>   will get the corresponding coat of arms. If 2 or more player
>   get last place this way, no negative points will be given to the
>   players ranked second to last

Comment: That's exactly where my question comes from. Two players are considered last, ok, there is no second to last player in this situation. Both of the "last" players should get the corresponding coat of arms, but there is only a single -10 in the box. What happens now?

Comment: @beam022 Both players get -10 to their score, just because they only include one token in the base game doesn't mean only one player gets the score. The situation where multiple players stay on 0 for the entire game is rare. Though if everyone stays on 0 then every player will get -10 for their score.